# Enable specific Middleware for Laravel phpunit test

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have `debug` Middleware which I have enabled for `api` middleware group. I'm writing test and doing some db operations. But it's not printing query in my Log file.

There's trait available `WithoutMiddleware`, but is there anything opposite to this available?

I've also tried adding middleware class to `protected $middleware`, but no luck.

**Update: debug middleware is just printing all queries in Log file, and it's working for API's.**

Comment: Would testing the middleware on its own do what you need? I usually write isolated unit tests for my middleware that don't touch anything else.

Comment: I want to check how many queries are getting fired for one of my model. So temporarily I'm doing it in test file.

Comment: did you found a solution for this?

Comment: @IvánSánchez I've created a package to log queries (https://packagist.org/packages/technoknol/log-my-queries), see if this helps

Comment: @shyammakwana.me I'm afraid that logging 's not problem. I'm looking for a general solution for enabling an specific middleware when using tests. I look at the BaseTest.php file where the `WithoutMiddleware` is declared but I couldn't find some solution. Anyway thanks I think I'm gonna go with the workaround

Comment: You're welcome :), I haven't touched it later, as I've worked with log only.